# Using Watin but Want to enter CaptCha manually!

Tags: watin, captcha

I'm using Using Watin with my project..I want all the things to be automated and Watin is doing that well. But I need the captha entry part to be done! I have to do this manually! Is there any way to popup an input box to get the Captcha Value and Watin will continue then???

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented that exact functionality on this PoC [API_GMail.cs](http://code.google.com/p/o2platform/source/browse/trunk/O2_Scripts/APIs/GMail/API_GMail.cs) I wrote for the [O2 Platform](http://o2platform.com).

Here is a video of it in action http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTD31e7HY4E

Here is the WatiN ExtensionMethods that make it easy to consume from a script: [WatiN_IE_ExtensionMethods.cs](http://code.google.com/p/o2platform/source/browse/trunk/O2_Scripts/APIs/Windows/WatiN/WatiN_IE_ExtensionMethods.cs)